# Dado da variável identUsuario em branco na URL. Como resolver?

Tags: javascript, html

Equipamentos

```
      <!-- redireciona os dados para atualizar levando o ID do equipamento  e identificação do usuário a ser redirecionado-->

     <script type="text/javascript">
        function reservar(){
        var identUsuario = identUsuario;
        var formReserva = document.forms[0];
        formReserva.action="MainServlet?acao=reservaEquipamento&idequipamento=${param.idequipamento}&identUsuario=${param.identUsuario}";  // Dado identUsuario vem em branco na URL
        formReserva.submit();

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="caixa-topo">
      <h1>SGCI</h1>
      <p> SISTEMA PARA GERENCIAMENTO COORDENAÇÃO DE INFORMÁTICA</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bara-topo u-full-width">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="topo">
        <span class="itens">ADMINISTRADOR</span>
        <span class="flaticon-power27 itens u-pull-right"></span>
        <span class="flaticon-info27 itens u-pull-right"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="twelve columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="equipamentos">
          <div class="four columns">
            <div class="menu-equipamento">
              <p>
                  <a href="equipamento.jsp"><img src="icones/eqp.png"></a><br><label>Reserva Equipamentos</label>
              <p>
              <hr width="50%">
              <a href="cadastraEquipamento.jsp"><img src="icones/adceqp.png">Cadastrar<br></a>
              <a href="MainServlet?acao=consultarEquipamento"><img src="icones/edteqp.png" alt="Editar">Alterar/Remover<br></a>
              <a href="MainServlet?acao=consultarReservaEquipamento"><img src="icones/rsveqp.png"></span>Reservar<br></a>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="eight columns">
              <p class="u-pull-left">Informações do equipamento:</p> 



            <!-- dados do equipamentos a ser reservado-->                                  
              <table>
              <tr><td class="hidden">${param.idequipamento}</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Nome:</td><td> ${param.nome}</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Marca:</td><td> ${param.marca}</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Código:</td><td> ${param.codigo}</td></tr>
              </table>

              <form method="post" id="consultaEquipamentos" action="#">
              <span>Número de identificação do usuário:</span><br/> 
              <input type="text" name="identUsuario">
              <input type="button" onClick="reservar()">
              </form>

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="rodape">
    <p>Tecno System Empresa Júnior - UNEB, todos os direitos reservados.</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: o IdentUsuario que ta sendo atribuído ta vindo de onde?

Comment: Oi! Está vindo do formulário <input type="text" name="identUsuario">

Comment: Não há informações suficientes na pergunta. Essas expressões ${...} não *existem* no HTML, você deve estar usando uma linguagem que se compila para HTML ou uma linguagem ao lado do servidor, mas nem cita ela na pergunta. Se `"${param.identUsuario}"` é um tipo de cadeia de caracteres, então não se esqueça de cobrir ela com \`, \' ou \" e lembre-se de usar os métodos do DOM para obter elementos.

Comment: Estou usando JSP.  E isso "${param.idequipamento}" é Expression language (EL) que permite acessar dados armazenados e trazer p interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que pegar o valor do input que o user digitar , e não atribuir já o nome do campo, tenta assim:

Adiciona um identificador no campo que tu quer:

```
<input type="text" name="identUsuario" id="ident_user">
```

Pega o valor dele via javascript e atribui à variável:

```
var identUsuario = document.querySelector("#ident_user").value;
```

Ai depois faz o que quiser com ele.

Comment: Então, já havia tentado com document.getElementById e nem assim está passando o dado T-T
Se tiver outras ideias, compartilha, por favor.

Comment: Provavelmente seja porque você está chamando o script de capturar o elemento antes dele ser renderizado na tela, mova os seus scripts para antes do final do body , assim a tela é renderizada com seus elementos e com isso o javascript pode capturar eles.

Comment: Desculpa a demora. Não resolve o problema, o script só é acionado quando clicado o botão no form, então os dados já tarão renderizados, tanto é, que os outros dados estão passando, com exceção do identUsuario. Porém, obrigada.

Comment: Você falou que ta usando o get..ById() sendo que não havia um id no elemento, no meu , adicionei uma id somente pra capturar ele. Tentou usar com o id?